# How to load JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) in my javascript file

Tags: javascript, drupal, jwt

I'm in custom module for Drupal, and i need to use JWT in javascript.

So i tried `npm i jsonwebtoken` and `import jwt from "../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js";` on my `js/index.js`

But i have the following error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`

I dont understand what to do and how i can load my library jsonwebtoken.

Sorry i'm really a beginner in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

When you import node modules you don't enter the relative path. You only put the name of the module your trying to import. Also the module dosnt have a default module which means you need to import everything into one variable or import specific functions.

## Javascript

If you use javascript you should use require instead of import. The example below is taken from their docs.

```js
// reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token = jwt.sign('payload', 'secret');
```

## Typescript

// quick and dirty

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
```

// This is the way you should do it

```
import {sign, decode, JsonWebTokenError, TokenExpiredError, verify, NotBeforeError} from 'jsonwebtoken'
```

I created an `example.ts` file and run the following commands.

```sh
npm i -s jsonwebtoken && npm i -D @types/jsonwebtoken
```

So my structure is somthing like this

- project

  - node_modules
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json
  - example.ts

Then I added those 2 lines to get the result below

```
import {sign} from 'jsonwebtoken';

sign('foo-bar', 'secret', undefined, ((err, res) => console.log(res)));
```

Console: `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.Zm9vLWJhcg.o2WiQrAIplX3gvloUOTaxCTlvmsWhFwxk9rh6xHoFs8`

Comment: Also in the second example of cause you should only import the functions that you actually use in that file.

Comment: How does javascript know where to look? (he can't find it).
For require i have the following error : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: When you don't provide a path it looks in the node modules. Otherwise if a path is provided it will look for the path. This is not the main issue in your case just a best pracise.

Comment: The problem is the way you import the module. Since the way you do it a default export is required in the index.js file of jwt. However the jwt module exports its functions separatly, so you need to import the specific functions that you require (see example 2) or import all functions as one object (see example 1). If you provide more code I can help with your usecase.

Comment: with relative path i have the following error : The requested module './../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js' does not provide an export named 'decode' :(
without relative path, he cant find it.

Comment: I managed to encode an payload with those 2 lines of code. 
import {sign} from 'jsonwebtoken';
sign('foo-bar', 'secret', undefined, ((err, res) => console.log(res)));

```

Are you using Typescript or Javascript?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm using javascript. My error is "The requested module './../node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js' does not provide an export named 'sign'". I dont understand..

Comment: I added the example of the offical docs. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken for reference. You should use require if you don't use typescript. However I believe their might be an issue with either your project structure or your package.json because it apparently cant find the node modules on its own.

Comment: Thanks ! I got "require is not defined" T_T

Comment: I tried it out here without any issue whatsoever. https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-sanne-cyic7?file=/index.js

Comment: Thanks i try tomorrow ! (otherwise I would go through php)